# Python json.dumps object when used in String context has length restrictions

Tags: python, json

I have the following condition. A dict "result" passed to json.dumps as follows. The dict 'result', and output are printed out as shown below.

```
dumpclean(result)
jsonString = json.dumps(result)
dumpclean(jsonString)
print "Value being sent to server is %s" % jsonString
```

Here dumpclean implementation is as follows

```
def dumpclean(obj):
    if type(obj) == dict:
        for k, v in obj.items():
            if hasattr(v, '__iter__'):
                print k
                dumpclean(v)
            else:
                print '%s : %s' % (k, v)
    elif type(obj) == list:
        for v in obj:
            if hasattr(v, '__iter__'):
                dumpclean(v)
            else:
                print v
    else:
        print obj
```

The output I see in log is something strange

```
2015-07-04 10:47:06 route_id : DEMPUN0001027
2015-07-04 10:47:06 version : 1
2015-07-04 10:47:06 frequency : 1
2015-07-04 10:47:06 end_time : 08:00
2015-07-04 10:47:06 type : schoolbuspickup
2015-07-04 10:47:06 points
2015-07-04 10:47:06 Latitude : 18.5123307247
2015-07-04 10:47:06 display_name : Check Point 0
2015-07-04 10:47:06 id : DEMPUN0001027000
2015-07-04 10:47:06 Longitude : 73.7916469574
2015-07-04 10:47:06 Latitude : 18.5112523117
2015-07-04 10:47:06 display_name : Check Point 1
2015-07-04 10:47:06 id : DEMPUN0001027001
2015-07-04 10:47:06 Longitude : 73.7930846214
2015-07-04 10:47:06 Latitude : 18.5095634624
2015-07-04 10:47:06 display_name : Check Point 2
2015-07-04 10:47:06 id : DEMPUN0001027002
2015-07-04 10:47:06 Longitude : 73.7935996056
2015-07-04 10:47:06 Latitude : 18.5081798145
2015-07-04 10:47:06 display_name : Check Point 3
2015-07-04 10:47:06 id : DEMPUN0001027003
2015-07-04 10:47:06 Longitude : 73.7945008278
2015-07-04 10:47:06 Latitude : 18.5073658988
2015-07-04 10:47:06 display_name : Check Point 4
2015-07-04 10:47:06 id : DEMPUN0001027004
2015-07-04 10:47:06 Longitude : 73.7984704971
2015-07-04 10:47:06 Latitude : 18.5067554594
2015-07-04 10:47:06 display_name : Check Point 5
2015-07-04 10:47:06 id : DEMPUN0001027005
2015-07-04 10:47:06 Longitude : 73.8006162643

2015-07-04 10:47:06 {"display_name": "Trial1", "start_time": "07:00", "days_valid": ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"], "route_id": "DEMPUN0001027", "version": 1, "frequency": 1, "end_time": "08:00", "type": "schoolbuspickup", "points": [{"Latitude": 18.5123307247275, "display_name": "Check Point 0", "id": "DEMPUN0001027000", "Longitude": 73.79164695739746}, {"Latitude": 18.511252311658, "display_name": "Check Point 1", "id": "DEMPUN0001027001", "Longitude": 73.79308462142944}, {"Latitude": 18.5095634624415, "display_name": "Check Point 2", "id": "DEMPUN0001027002", "Longitude": 73.7935996055603}, {"Latitude": 18.5081798145188, "display_name": "Check Point 3", "id": "DEMPUN0001027003", "Longitude": 73.7945008277893}, {"Latitude": 18.5073658987508, "display_name": "Check Point 4", "id": "DEMPUN0001027004", "Longitude": 73.79847049713135}, {"Latitude": 18.506755459385, "display_name": "Check Point 5", "id": "DEMPUN0001027005", "Longitude": 73.80061626

2015-07-04 10:47:06 Value being sent to server is {"display_name": "Trial1", "start_time": "07:00", "days_valid": ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"], "route_id": "DEMPUN0001027", "version": 1, "frequency": 1, "end_time": "08:00", "type": "schoolbuspickup", "points": [{"Latitude": 18.5123307247275, "display_name": "Check Point 0", "id": "DEMPUN0001027000", "Longitude": 73.79164695739746}, {"Latitude": 18.511252311658, "display_name": "Check Point 1", "id": "DEMPUN0001027001", "Longitude": 73.79308462142944}, {"Latitude": 18.5095634624415, "display_name": "Check Point 2", "id": "DEMPUN0001027002", "Longitude": 73.7935996055603}, {"Latitude": 18.5081798145188, "display_name": "Check Point 3", "id": "DEMPUN0001027003", "Longitude": 73.7945008277893}, {"Latitude": 18.5073658987508, "display_name": "Check Point 4", "id": "DEMPUN0001027004", "Longitude": 73.79847049713135}, {"Latitude": 18.506755459385, "display_name": "Check Point 5", "id": "DEMPUN0001027
```

It seems as the output of json.dumps when used in a string context is getting truncated. So is there a length of string restriction for the print function
?

The main issue is the jsonString so generated when used to in a 'POST' is also resulting in a truncated JSON being posted.

```
req = Request("http://xyz/api/v1/Route/" + routeCode, jsonString)
response = urlopen(req)
```

SOLUTION:

This is related to the field size restriction of the cache implementation used to store JSON on receiving server. It was not big enough to cover for larger JSON data.

Comment: There is no such restriction in Python, no. Your *terminal or console* may have such a restriction, though.

Comment: This code is running on AWS. And results are same if run on local machine (Ubuntu),

Comment: You didn't show anything about how you are printing this. `print` doesn't add the timestamps either, so *something* is processing this data. That something is truncating the string, most likely.

Comment: I'm confused. So your problem is not with `print` at all, but with a truncated string you `print`, right?

Comment: Try to write your string into file: `open("file.txt","w").write(jsonString)`. For HTTP request use http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Comment: I tried using json.loads and recovering the dict. And it is fine. Which would mean that jsonString object is not actually truncated. But when this object is being referred in a 'String' context it seems to be truncated (eg print, Request)

Comment: @MarcusMüllerꕺꕺ Yes. The issue was that jsonString object generated by passing a dict to json.dumps when sent as data of a Request (POST) the receiving server also sees a truncated string. But when I recover dict from jsonString using json.loads I do see it is perfectly fine. Hence I think this object from json.dumps when used in String context is getting truncated

Comment: @prasunnair: almost certainly not. There is no such thing as what you call "string context". the output of json.dumps is simply a string.

Comment: @MarcusMüllerꕺꕺ  But then how can we justify the result. When I pass this to json.loads I am able to recover the dict. But when I pass it to Request and receive the data it is a truncated String. I think I need to check the receiver side to see if it is goofing something up.

Comment: @prasunnair: that's a good question! But I still doubt your debugging techniques, especially since you say the same string loads fine using `json.loads`. I don't know your server implementation, but its much more likely that just doesn't receive all the data in one call than a python string being truncated in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So is there a length of string restriction for the print function ?

No. Python just passes on the string to the output.

Your logger, however, will very very likely have such a per-line limit to keep programs from making the log file size explode.

Comment: Ok. But when I pass this json.dumps Object to Request to generate a HTTP POST, the receiving server is also getting a truncated JSON. Updated the question with code

Comment: Was and issue with field size of SQL table used to store the JSON on receiving server. Updated the question with solution. Thanks !!